Was there ever a Ziffer 5 of §61 StPO read around 1977, and if yes, what did it read?
In an answer by Peter, the following statement appears:

An interesting detail is that at that time (1977, probably) apparently the court could refrain from demanding an oath if the defendants agreed. That "Ziffer 5" must since have been removed from §61 of the Code of Criminal Procedure (StPO).

This is based on a film's depiction of the law, so there might be truth, or just artistic license, or ecen a number error, but in general:
What was this §61 StPO Ziffer 5, if it ever existed?

§61 StPO is about the rights of relatives as defined in §52 (they don't have to testify in the first place, so making them swear oaths would be silly). Also the oath is the exception, not the rule (§ 59 StPO), so the court does not have to refrain, they can just decide it is not necessary. And if people don't want to swear oaths deemed necessary by the court, they can make a declaration "an Eides statt" which has the same legal consequences. I can't find a historic version of the StPO, but that hypothetical Ziffer 5 would not make sense.

Wann kann nach dem § 61 Nr. 5 StPO. wegen Unerheblichkeit der Aussage von der Vereidigung eines Zeugen abgesehen werden? https://dejure.org/dienste/vernetzung/rechtsprechung?Gericht=RG&Datum=09.02.1937&Aktenzeichen=1%20D%202/37

@BernhardDöbler The claim of the character was kann von der vereidigung des zeugens abgesehen werden, wenn alle angeklagten zustimmen or something. The Law apparently was changed in 2004, as your site links to.

@Trish the linked PDF with a document from 1937 states that "das Gericht kann von der Vereidigung absehen, wenn alle Mitglieder des Gerichts die Aussage für unerheblich halten", referring to § 61 Nr. 5 StPO. So apparently Ziffer 5 was a thing, although I doubt that defendants are "members of the court" (also StPO was revised in 1950, I am not sure how applicable this would be to the Stammheim process).

When can according to Section 61 No. 5 StPO. a witness should not be sworn in because the statement is irrelevant?
